# Expected number of draws before a given combination with probability $\geq$ 95%$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have balls in C colors and we draw them with replacement. What is the expected number of draws before we get at least $95%$ chance of drawing a given sequence of two colors (e.g. blue and then red)?

Edit:
There is infinite number of balls, so that drawing each color is equally probable.

My attempt was to calculate a set of equations where A = expected number of draws if we have just got the first required color and B = expected number of draws otherwise, but I don't know how to deal with this $95%$ probability.

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: Assuming there is one ball of each of the $C$ colors?

Comment: I edited the question.